# Can I change windows user login with python?

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I change windows user login with this code.

```
os.environ['username'] = 'Test'  
print(os.getenv('username'))
```

The output is:

```
Test
```

When I get current user with this code.

```
print(win32api.GetUserNameEx(win32api.NameSamCompatible))
```

It show output like this.

```
DESKTOP-B4I69EK\MyPC
```

The name `\MyPC` should change to `\Test`.

How to change windows user login with Python?

Comment: Do you realize that it would be a massive security hole if you could actually change to a new user that way?

Comment: The current user will show when I print file to cups printer on linux. So, I have to set the name of user who want to print as user logon.

Comment: If the user name for your logon session is the PC name, you're likely running as a SYSTEM service. What you can do is have the calling thread impersonate another user in the system -- maybe the user from the active console session, if any. While impersonating, `GetUserNameEx` will return the name of the impersonated user.

Comment: User name is connected to multiple services in Windows OS. You should not change the user name, because it will create a lot of problems in the future. Create a new user, migrate the data, and delete the old one.